# Embed Latex equation in LyX

Tags: math-mode, equations, lyx

I would like to transfer the LaTeX:

```
\begin{equation}
  W(\mathbf{F},\lambda_{\chi})=\min_{\textbf{R}\epsilon S^{2}}
\end{equation}
```

which gives the subscript `{\textbf{R}\epsilon S^{2}}` right under the "min" and centered, to my LyX file. Would you help? I cannot paste it, with "paste special from LaTeX" neither in a LyX equation setting, nor without the setting, and Ctrl L + $formula$ does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

Copy everything between `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}`, that is

```
W(\mathbf{F},\lambda_{\chi})=\min_{\mathbf{R}\epsilon S^{2}}
```

(I changed the `\textbf` to `\mathbf`) and paste it into a math-environment in LyX, just using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, not Paste Special.

With a normal displayed equation, added with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, you will get

[image]

Pasting everything including the `equation` environment into an ERT (without creating a math-environment first) will also work, but you wont get the preview.

Comment: Regarding "but you wont get the preview", *unless* you use a TeX box (Insert > Preview). But I agree that it is better as you suggest to paste directly into a math inset.

Comment: @scottkosty Yeah, thanks for reminding me about that.

Answer (score 0):

In lyx:

1- insert > math > arry environment.

2- in first row:

- add ( W ... = ) in the first square, then add ( min ) in the 2nd square.

3- in 2nd row:

- let first square empty.
- in the 2nd square add ( R ... ).

Without any tex code.

Regards

Comment: Sorry, using an array for this is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

the sloved in example

- insert > math > arry environment.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: i hope you merge it.